# sharpening an image after removing a Moiré pattern

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am attempting to remove a moire pattern from an image by blurring the image and then returning it to its original quality by enhancing and sharpening the image, however I can only seem to remove the pattern and leave it very blurry, which is not what I am trying to do.

I have tried to apply a filter to the image to blur the image and remove the checkerboard pattern however I cannot seem to return the image to its original quality without the checkerboard.

```
imageFiles = {'radiograph_01.jpg', 'radiograph_02.jpg'};
medWinSize = [7 11];
notchCenters{1} = [269 80; 261 123; 245 216; 238 258];
sigmas{1} = [45 20 20 45];
notchCenters{2} = [277 442; 209 450];
sigmas{2} = [20 20];
for nImage = 1:length(imageFiles)
% Load image
 [pathStr, name, ext] = fileparts(imageFiles{nImage});
 img = imread(imageFiles{nImage});
 img = im2double(img);
 [height, width] = size(img);
 figure(1); clf;
 subplot(1,3,1);
 imshow(img);

 % Median filter
 imgMed = medfilt2(img, medWinSize(nImage)*[1 1]);
 subplot(1,3,2);
 imshow(imgMed);
 imwrite(imgMed, [name '-med-filtered.jpg']);

 % Compute DFT of original image
 imgDFT = fftshift(fft2(img));
 imgDFTMag = abs(imgDFT);
 figure(2); clf;
 subplot(1,3,1);
 imshow(log(imgDFTMag), [0 10]); colorbar;

 % Apply notch filter
 [omega_x, omega_y] = meshgrid(1:width, 1:height);
 filterDFT = ones(size(omega_x));
 for n = 1:size(notchCenters{nImage},1)
 rSq = (omega_x - notchCenters{nImage}(n,1)).^2 + ...
 (omega_y - notchCenters{nImage}(n,2)).^2;
 filterDFT = filterDFT .* (1 - exp(-rSq / sigmas{nImage}(n)^2));
 end % n
 imgFiltDFT = imgDFT .* filterDFT;
 imgFiltDFTMag = abs(imgFiltDFT);
 subplot(1,3,2);
 imshow(filterDFT, [0 1]); colorbar;
 subplot(1,3,3);
 imshow(log(imgFiltDFTMag), [0 10]); colorbar;
 % Reconstruct image
 imgFilt = real(ifft2(ifftshift(imgFiltDFT)));
 imgFilt = max(0, min(1, imgFilt));
 figure(1);
 subplot(1,3,3);
 imshow(imgFilt);
 imwrite(imgFilt, [name '-notch-filtered.jpg']);
end % nImage
```

[image: Original Image]

With this current code, the image is loaded in, the filter is applied and the image is returned without the moire pattern, but still has a blurred effect on it. I am trying to sharpen this image an return it to its original quality after having removed this pattern.

Comment: I've downvoted your question since it is not [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

> but still has a blurred effect on it.

Thats because you deleted high frequencies with your Notch filter.

> I am trying to sharpen this image an return it to its original
>   quality

It is not possible to return the image to its original Moire free quality. Although you might be able to yield better results if you design your Notch filter more carefully.

Moire already destroyed information and removing those disturbing frequencies with the Notch filter destroyed even more.

You cannot get that information back. The only thing you can do is to apply some sharpening filters which usualy rely on increasing the [acutance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acutance). With such filters the image is actually not sharpened but edge transitions are manipulated in a way that makes them appear sharper.

There are other techniques than using Notch filters which in many cases perform better.

Read [A New Method for Removing the Moire' Pattern from
Images](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1701/1701.09037.pdf) for example. They use median filters.